# kubectl apply doesn't update service selector label

Tags: kubernetes, restful-url, kubectl, kubernetes-apiserver

right now I have a service

`kubectl get svc ray-test-svc`

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
   ....
    labels:
      app: ray-test-app
      service: ray-test-svc
    name: ray-test-svc
    namespace: ray-test-ns
  spec:
    ports:
    - nodePort: 30198
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8000
    selector:
      app: ray-test-app
      service: ray-test-svc
      version: v2
    type: LoadBalancer
```

After I edit my yaml file deleting the `version: v2` in selector and do

`kubectl apply -f ray-test-svc.yaml`

the `version:v2` is still in selector!

Here is my yaml file

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ray-test-svc
  annotations:
    ....
  labels:
    app: ray-test-app
    service: ray-test-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: ray-test-app
    service: ray-test-svc
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
```

I check the log by using `-v=9` seeing that kubectl uses `PATCH` to do the update. Is this a bug in kubeApi or is there any way to just delete partial labels? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like misconfiguration:
You didn't  set the `namespace`  in second YAML, and you apply it by command 
`kubectl apply -f ray-test-svc.yaml`. It will not update the old service, it will create a new one in namespace `default`. You can run command `kubectl apply -f ray-test-svc.yaml -n ray-test-ns` and it will update you service. Also you can add `namespace: ray-test-ns` to second YAML.

Comment: Yea I see that...Thank you

Comment: I wondering what is the difference if I add the namespace when typing `kubectl apply -f ray-test-svc.yaml -n ray-test-ns`  even if I miss the namespace in the spec?